# Why would you call array_shift on the matches returned from preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to develop a framework using PHP while learning, and came across this logic for URL routing using regex:

```
public static function on($regex, $cb)
{
    $params = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $params = (stripos($params, "/") !== 0) ? "/" . $params : $params;
    $regex = str_replace('/', '\/', $regex);
    $is_match = preg_match('/^' . ($regex) . '$/', $params, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    if ($is_match) {
       
        array_shift($matches);
        
        $params = array_map(function ($param) {
            return $param[0];
        }, $matches);
        $cb(new Request($params), new Response());
    }
}
```

I don't understand why `array_shift` is called on the `$matches` array after calling `preg_match`. Can anyone explain?

Comment: It is impossible to answer without knowing what this function should do and what is the expected result. Simply, I can say that that array_shift() delete the first element of the array

Comment: The code explicitly ensures that `$params` always starts with a slash. We don't know what `$regex` this actually gets called with, but presumably this is simply done to not have an "empty" first match.

Comment: @CBroe It's not about an empty first match, it's about the structure of the `$matches` array; see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The variable called `$matches` in this code is passed by reference to `preg_match` which populates it. According to [the documentation](https://www.php.net/preg_match):

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

To picture what this means, take a really simple pattern which always matches the same text, but splits it up into captured groups: `'/(abc)(def)/'` will match the string `abcdef`, and put `abc` in one group, and `def` in another group.

```
$matches = [];
preg_match('/(abc)(def)/', 'abcdef', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abcdef
    [1] => abc
    [2] => def
)
```

Note that the array contains the full matched string, `abcdef`, and then the two groups. So if we just want the groups, we need to ignore the first element of the array. One way to do that is to use [`array_shift`](https://php.net/array_shift), which "shifts" the first element off the front of an array, re-numbering everything that's left:

```
array_shift($matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => def
)
```

Now we can loop over the array, knowing that we just have the parts we captured into groups.

In the context of URL matching, you might have a pattern like `/calendar/(\d+)/(\d+)/` which matches `/calendar/2022/10/`. If `preg_match` returns 1, you know that the pattern has matched, so you just want to map the two numbers to variables to use in the page.